# How to use Suggester component with Solr.Net

Tags: c#, .net, solr, solrnet

I am able to configure the [Suggester](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester) component with Solr but how do I query it with Solr.Net? Is it supported?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194794/how-to-get-the-suggester-component-working-in-solrnet

Answer (score 1):

The suggester component is not currently implemented in SolrNet. It is listed as an open issue within the SolrNet project - [Issue 141 - Suggester Component Support](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=141)