# c# solrnet searching multiwords and phrase

Tags: c#, search, solrnet

I would like to use autocomplete in my site. I start using [solrnet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/). when the user start typing a sentence I would like to return results with exact match and after that "startswith". The thing is that I can't seem to get the multiwords sentence to work with "startwith". any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194794/how-to-get-the-suggester-component-working-in-solrnet

Answer (score 0):

There is a Suggester functionality in Solr that you can use.

Check how you can configure it here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester

SolrNet has not much to dod with it though, I think for it the field is just like a normal field.